# Reading stdin with separate thread in C++

Tags: c++, multithreading, stdin

I am trying to get a separate thread to read stdin while the main program runs a search algorithm. It should ideally set some stop/quit flags that the main thread can then read.

I currently have the following code:

```
void COMM::listen_for_input(bool stopset, long long stoptime) {
    std::string input = "";

    while (!stopset || getTimeMs() < stoptime) {
        input = "";
        std::getline(std::cin, input);


        if (input.find("quit") != std::string::npos) {
            ld.quit = true;
            return;
        }
    
        if (input.find("stop") != std::string::npos) {
            ld.stop = true;
            return;
        }

        if ((stopset && getTimeMs() >= stoptime) || Search::isStop.load(std::memory_order_relaxed)) {
            return;
        }

    }
}
```

Where ld is just a global struct consisting of a "bool stop" and "bool quit", which the main thread will then read. I assume that this is thread safe since only the listener thread actually writes to the struct?

The Search::isStop is an atomic bool that the main thread uses to signal to the other workers that they should stop searching (in case of multithreaded search).

Just before I launch the main thread, I set up the listener:

```
std::thread listener(COMM::listen_for_input, info->timeset, info->stoptime);

/*  Run the main thread  */

listener.join();
```

My problem is that the listener.join() call just waits until the listen_for_input() function actually reads a "stop" or a "quit". I have checked with the debugger that the searcher-threads join properly, and that the program just waits when calling listener.join(). This means that they stop due to time-out (using the same logic with getTimeMs() >= stoptime), which implies that this thread should be able to do the same... Additionally, I have checked that it reads "stop" and "quit" correctly; It just won't join unless one of those are given..

What am I doing wrong that causes the while loop to never terminate? What is the best way of listening for input on stdin with a separate thread?

Thanks in advance :))

Comment: `listener.detach();` instead of `listener.join();` ? I'm having trouble understanding your question.

Comment: My question is that I want a thread to listen for input from stdin while the main thread runs an algorithm at the same time. The main thread should then be able to see if there has been a "stop" or "quit" command from the user/gui (the program is usually controlled by a GUI). I will try listener.detatch()